# Apparent paradox in the Booster and Announcer Badges

Tags: discussion, badges

I am curious. I read the description of the badges, and I have been submitting a shared link to search engines to see if I could get them exposed to many people. The description says you cannot get both badges for the same shared item... and it says you can get the Announcer badge more than once. So I have gotten the Announcer badge for all 3 links I shared, and if then I cannot get the Booster for them (is that really true?) then has something changed or does it not always award the first badge? ...Or does it actually give you both badges for the same link anyway?

Comment: where did you read the description?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/

Comment: this one states: "Each badge can be earned only once, and each must be earned on a different question. "

Comment: but then I see a comment in here that says Announcer can be gained many times, so apparently either they are different or changed over time.

Comment: Submitting your tagged links to a search engine isn't really what the purpose of this badge is. Search engines already know about Stack Exchange.

Comment: Not the only place I shared it since I posted that, thanks for the info

Comment: Articles posted on facebook, twitter, reddit, to name a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The badges page for [Announcer](https://superuser.com/help/badges/64/announcer), [Booster](https://superuser.com/help/badges/65/booster) and [Publicist](https://superuser.com/help/badges/66) do not mention that you cannot get both the badges for the same shared it.

The badges used to [work differently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/188733/revisions) when first introduced(there were timelimit/IP limit changes since then) <s>but I don't remember any changes which mention that the same question cannot multiple badges of the class you mention</s> and the order in [which they are](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118638/133693) awarded were [indeed changed later on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118484/booster-badge-should-be-golden-or-easier-to-achieve/118509#118509)

Comment: @JeffClayton blog is indeed out of date, look at my edit